# Why am I getting a TemplateDoesNotExist error in Django 4.0 when the template does exist?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm new to Django, and I've been struggling with this TemplateDoesNotExist error for a while. I looked at many other users who were having these issues, but none of the proposed solutions seem to work for me.

Django cannot find my blog/base.html file and claims it looks in '/home/agile/django_project/blog/templates/blog/base.html' for it, but when I check in my ubuntu, it says the directory exists fine?

When I run on my localhost, the site works fine, but when working with ubuntu and Linode is when I run into this problem.

[Image of Django error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuFfq.png)

[Image of the path that exists but Django can't find?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4rCc.png)

Again, I have tried many 'solutions' by adding to template DIRS and stuff but honestly, none have worked. I just don't know what is wrong/how to go about fixing it. Any help I would greatly appreciate.

**UPDATE:**

**I was able to fix it. I accidently put "blog/base.html " instead of "blog/base.html"**

Here is my settings.py file, too:

````
Django settings for django_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/


from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-e5oqam$0o(1158xprooll%5dg)xk01nw8alh6z1cv@)674^48k'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["45.56.100.252"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


#using this method makes sure full path to directory is created correctly no matter OS.
#BASE_DIR means media root will be at projects base directory.
#media is where uploaded files will be placed
#media url is how we access that image in the browser
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '...'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'fiftftlyutyokgnu'```
````

Comment: The problem is that you have an extra space before the closing `"`:  `{% extends "blog/base.html " %}`

Comment: and to think I spent so much time and didn't notice, thank you so much!! It worked :D

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py use this in you templates

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Before I kept putting 'templates' in place of 'blog', so I thought it would work. Unfortunately, the error still keeps popping up. I wonder why?

Comment: can you show me view where you are referencing template?

Comment: you should have `templates` directory in your project root folder and <appname> directories with html templates in it. Then in your settings.py `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]` should work

Comment: and in your `views.py` you'll have `return render(request, "blog/home.html")` etc.